# Assign Vector3D array using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, vector

I'm looking for a smooth way to assign a Vector3D[] array using LINQ (and not looping). Is this possible?

I'm new to LINQ methods and I just started figuring out how to assign a whole array in a single line of code. For example:

```
double[] angle_in_radians = angle_in_degrees .Select(x => x / 180 * Math.PI).ToArray();
```

Suppose now I have the `angle_in_radians` array above and I want to use it in a vector3D array:

```
Vector3D[] example_vector = new Vector3D[n];
```

the way I solve the problem today is using a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     example_vector[i] = new Vector3D(Math.Cos(angle_in_radians[i]), Math.Sin(angle_in_radians[i]), 0);
}
```

I can't really figure out how to use linq (if it's even possible). I want to somehow put:

```
angle_in_radians.Select(x => Math.Cos(x)).ToArray();
```

in all of the Vector3D X positions and the same with Y and Z.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Is there any reason you want to replace a perfectly readable and performant for-loop with LINQ?

Comment: Note: Unless you specifically need an array (e.g. for compatibility with code you don't control), a `List` is generally preferable when converting from an `IEnumerable` to a collection.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Thank you :). I don't really have a good reason, just used with MatLab one-line assignments if you know what I mean. I'm still trying to figure out what suits me more.

Comment: @NetMage: I see, I will consider it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace a for loop by linq select like that :

```
var example_vectors = angle_in_radians.Select(x => new Vector3D(Math.Cos(x), Math.Sin(x), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I modified it into: Vector3D[] SurfVecContact = NormT.Select(x => new Vector3D(Math.Cos(x), Math.Sin(x), 0)).ToArray();